# How to simultaneously add application and device to multiple tests in a compound Test in IBM MobilefirstPlatform Test Workbench 8.6.0

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-mtw

**Tool Used:** IBM Mobilefirst Platform TestWorkbench 8.6.0 
**Operating System:** Windows 7

Have created multiple test scripts using the record feature in Test workbench
Have created a new Compound test and have added the test scripts to the compound test

When i click "**Run Compound Test**" i get a window "Run Configuration" and a message in the window reads 'Test(s) contains reference to missing application(s). Add or Import them and try to run again'

I have to individually add application to each test, then the above error resolves. I want to add the application and Device to all tests simultaneously in one go. Is there a way to do this ?


This option would be helpful when we have 100 test cases in a Compound test, and we get a new application to test daily

Comment: What is your exact MTW build number? 8.6.0.x, x=?

Comment: MTW build number is 8.6.0.1

Comment: Hi Idan, figured it out.

Comment: Please supply the solution as an answer to the question below.

Answer (score 1):

1)In Test Workbench perspective Open "Mobile and Web UI Applications" Tab 
2)In this tab Go to "Available Tests" subtab. Select all Test Cases.
3) Click on button "Replace application by another one in selected Test suites".

4)Then a couple of windows open. Click OK,..OK.. 
5)And the old app is replaced by new one in all Test cases in a single go. 
6)Add all these Test cases to Compound Test

Answer (score 0):

Run of compound test is supported in MTWW.
The message ( 'Test(s) contains reference to missing application(s). Add or Import them and try to run again') mean that you have one or more test cases that are not link anymore to any application. You can open these test cases and linked it again to a new app that you have imported as described above.

**Important**: When you add a new version of an existing application in MTWW, you should be prompted to link your old test cases to the new one.

You have also a pref to avoid to be prompted and do that automatically (Open the prefs, and go in Text > Mobile & Web UI > general Settings)

Dominique